# Onsen UI page transitions

Tags: onsen-ui

How do you control speed, duration and responsiveness of the page transitions in Onsen UI pages?

Also, how to put transition for resetToPage()?

Thanks

Comment: Also interested in this, aswell as how to add transition to <ons-tabbar>

Answer (score 1):

For now, I think there are no way to control page transition duration in Onsen UI.
I'm not sure when you say "responsiveness" and " how to put transition for resetToPage()"

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Ataru.  resetToPage() currently just quick cut to the main screen, no transition at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the variables that are initiated in onsenui.js. Some of the animation and responsiveness can be handled through that.

Example, you can run a command like this just after including onsenui.js:
Hammer.gestures.Swipe.defaults.swipeVelocityX = 0.2;

Answer (score 0):

As for `resetToPage()`, it takes `options` argument as a second parameter. You can assign animation there.

https://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#method-resetToPage